# Set wallpaper from terminal in xfce4 on linux mint

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, xfce

I want to set the wallpaper from terminal on a Linux 18.1 with xfce4:

I've tried setting it using `xfconf-query`:

```
xfconf-query \
  --channel xfce4-desktop  \
  --property /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path \
  --set /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-teal.jpg
```

Indeed, when I later query the same setting with:

```
xfconf-query \
  --channel xfce4-desktop  \
  --property /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path
```

it returns the string:

```
/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-teal.jpg
```

However, this setting seems to have no bearing on anything, the visible wallpaper stays the same. How do I change the actual background from terminal? Thanks.

Additional information:

```
$ xfconf-query --version
xfconf-query 4.12.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct setting can be found out using the `-m` flag (short for `--monitor`). First, start `xfconf-query` in monitoring mode:

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -m 
Start monitoring channel "xfce4-desktop":

set: /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/workspace0/last-image
set: /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/workspace0/last-image
set: /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/workspace0/last-image
set: /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/workspace0/last-image
set: /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/workspace0/last-image
```

When you then go into the GUI and change the background there, the console application will print lines starting with `set:`, which show which properties have been changed.

Now, using

```
$ xfconf-query  \
  --channel xfce4-desktop \
  --property /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/workspace0/last-image \
  --set /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-blue.jpg
```

you can set the wallpaper from terminal.