# Set wallpaper from cron in xfce4

Tags: linux, cron, xfce4

I've written a little script `createCountdownWallpaper.py` that is supposed to re-render the wallpaper `/tmp/wallpaper.png` every few minutes, and a script `setWallpaper.sh` that looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/path/to/countdown
/usr/bin/python3.5 createCountdownWallpaper.py

xfconf-query  \
  --channel xfce4-desktop \
  --property /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/last-image \
  --set /tmp/wallpaper.png
```

The channels and `property` have been selected using `-m` flag of `xfconf-query`, as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1327821/set-wallpaper-from-terminal-in-xfce4-on-linux-mint/1327824#1327824). It works when run from the terminal. However, when run from `cron`, it seems to have no effect. Crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

*/1 * * * * /home/path/to/countdown/setWallpaper.sh 2>/tmp/cron_errors.txt
```

I've also tried sourcing various `.bashrc` and `.profile` scripts and setting environment variables like

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=tmp/dbus-r4nd0MjunK
```

but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this before running `xfconf-query`:

```
PID=$(echo $(ps -C xfce4-session -o pid=))                                      
export $(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following combination seemed to work, it re-renders and changes the background every minute.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

*/1 * * * * yourUsername source $HOME/.profile ; source $HOME/.bashrc; env DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/path/to/countdown/setWallpaper.sh 2>/tmp/cron_errors.txt
```

Hints:

- `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` does not seem to matter
- The `Folder: /tmp` setting in the GUI "Desktop" menu *does* matter
- **The automatic changing of wallpapers every `N` minutes must be deactivated in the XFCE-gui for wallpaper settings**.